# Ansible Ad-Hoc command with ssh keys

Tags: networking, ansible, juniper, ansible-ad-hoc

I would like to setup ansible on my Mac. I've done something similar in GNS3 and it worked but here there are more factors I need to take into account. so I have the Ansible installed. I added hostnames in /etc/hosts and I can ping using the hostnames I provided there.

I have created ansible folder which I am going to use and put ansible.cfg inside:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = ./hosts
host_key_checking = false
timeout = 5
inventory = ./hosts
```

In the same folder I have hosts file:

```
[tp-lab]
lab-acc0
```

When I try to run the following command: ansible tx-edge-acc0 -m ping

I am getting the following errors:

```
[WARNING]: Invalid characters were found in group names but not replaced, use -vvvv to see details
[WARNING]: Unhandled error in Python interpreter discovery for host tx-edge-acc0: unexpected output from Python interpreter discovery
[WARNING]: sftp transfer mechanism failed on [tx-edge-acc0]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: scp transfer mechanism failed on [tx-edge-acc0]. Use ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1 to see detailed information
[WARNING]: Platform unknown on host tx-edge-acc0 is using the discovered Python interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information.
tx-edge-acc0 | FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to tx-edge-acc0 closed.\r\n",
    "module_stdout": "\r\nerror: unknown command: /bin/sh\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error",
    "rc": 0
```

Any idea what might the problem here? much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it seems that you ansible controller does not load configuration files (especially ansible.cfg) when playbook is fired.

(*From documentation*) Ansible searches for configuration files in the following order, processing the first file it finds and ignoring the rest:

1. `$ANSIBLE_CONFIG` if the environment variable is set.
2. `ansible.cfg` if it’s in the current directory.
3. `~/.ansible.cfg` if it’s in the user’s home directory.
4. `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`, the default config file.

Edit: For peace of mind it is good to use full paths

**EDIT Based on comments**

```
$ cat /home/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
inventory = /home/ansible/hosts  # <-- use full path to inventory file

$ cat /home/ansible/hosts
[servers]
server-a
server-b
```

Command & output:

```
# Supplying inventory host group! 
$ ansible servers -m ping
server-a | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
server-b | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Comment: I managed to bring it up however cannot perform the basic ansible ping. Please check my update and thanks for helping

Comment: Is python installed on target server? If so tweak interpreter, eg `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: No there's not Python installed on a target server. It's just a ping so shouldn't be needed?

Comment: Yes, because you are running command `ping` on server mentioned in inventory file. You can verify it by using some remote web server (eg facebook.com, google.com) in your inventory filese

Comment: Ok. I have now created a playbook and enabled the netconf on the remote switch but still getting the following:
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Connection type ssh is not valid for netconf_get module. Valid connection type is netconf."}

Comment: This is for completely new issue....
But [HERE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/network/getting_started/network_differences.html) is where you have to start